# Image changes the layout of a link when it gets visible

Tags: css, layout

If I set the style of image to `display inline` by clicking a button by javascript then it becomes shown and a link `a` changes its layout a little bit.

```
   <span>
     <a href="#">my link</a>
     <img  src="mygif.gif" style="display: none;">
   </span>
```

How do I get rid off that?  I need that setting the image visible doesn't change the layout of `a`.

Comment: Hey now define a tag display inline-block

Comment: What do you mean by layout of a is changed. Plzz put your code on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: go to AreYouWatchingMe.org and click "more photos" on bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by changes layout.

My jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yk5GH/ shows that the anchor link gets pushed down, if you don't want that set the image as `block` and the image will show below the anchor link.